# Laravel dynamic table creation

Tags: database, laravel

I am developing an application with Laravel, I wanted to ask if it is possible that when a user logs in through a consultation this create a table since I've only seen in the documentation for DB, select, insert, update, statement, and I wanted to ask that way could the user with a query to create a table, could be done as follows ?

```
DB :: statement ('create table example (// table settings)');
```

but this query returns nothing.

Comment: This is very unclear. Try to reword the question or show an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you get it sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question. User controls table creation?? This logic seems like a really bad idea. But none the less, you can create a new table by:

```
Schema::create('table_name',function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    ...
});
```

More info can be found here...
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-tables